# Delete a item by ID in list inside other list in mongodb using C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, .net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a structure like **University have a list of classes. Classes have a list of students.**
I made CRUDs for 3 entities in mongodb and everything is ok, except the delete in the student object.

I have a json like that

```
{
  "id": "u01",
  "classes": [
    {
      "id": "c01",
      "students": [
        {
          "id": "s01",
          "name": "Ana"
        },
        {
          "id": "s02",
          "name": "Jonh"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need pull id S02 using dot.net and tried use pullFilter

```
    var filter = Builders<University>.Filter.And(Builders<University>.Filter.ElemMatch(doc => doc.Classes, c => c.Id == "c01"));
    var update = Builders<University>.Update.PullFilter(c => c.Classes.First().Students, item => item.Id == "s02");
    collection.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(filter, update);
```

I have no exceptions but didn't work.
What´s wrong? Ty for help

Comment: Is `university` a property in your document or is `{ id: "u01", classes: ... }` the document? If you use `var result = await collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update)`, what is returned for `MatchedCount` and `ModifiedCount`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.
The json is simplyfied to this example, but is working fine to all other cruds in other levels

MatchedCount = 1
ModifiedCount = 0

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove the student from the first class that matched the filter, you'd specify the field in [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#mongodb-update-up.-) like this:

```
classes.$.students
```

In C#, you can mimic this by using an index of -1, e.g.:

```
var update = Builders<University>
  .Update
  .PullFilter(c => c.Classes.ElementAt(-1).Students, item => item.Id == "s02");
```